# Is there a built-in method to get the max index of a List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Is there a built in method in C# to get the max index in a List ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't a built-in method. You can always use

```
int maxIndex = myList.Count - 1;
```

For a List, you are guaranteed that the elements will be in the range 0..Count-1, so you can create an extension method:

```
public static int LastIndex<T>(this List<T> list)
{
  return list.Count-1;
}
```

Off course, these lines will return -1 when the list has 0 elements, which might be a problem.

Comment: This the thing I don't want. I was wondering if there is a built in method to achieve this without writing -1 (I can also write an extension method as well. But is there a built in method there?)

Comment: @pencilCake, as SWeko states there *is not a built in method*.  So, use "-1" or create the extension method.  Those are your choices :)

Answer (score 8):

The maximum valid index is always the size - 1, so:

```
int maxIndex = list.Count - 1;
```

If you want to get the *value* at the last index in a very readable way, you could use LINQ:

```
var item = list.Last();
```

Note that this won't be *quite* as efficient as using `list[list.Count - 1]` but it *won't* be an O(n) operation - LINQ to Objects is optimized in various places to take advantage of `IList<T>`.

Comment: If not O(n) does it mean it will be O(1) ?

Comment: Keep in mind pencilCake that if the `List` is empty it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when using `Last()`.

Comment: @pencilCake No, it doesn't. It could be, say, O(log n)

Comment: @pencilCake: with the current implementation of both Enumerable.Last and `List<T>` it will be O(1). I don't expect that to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the index of the max value then no, there isn't. You could probably write an extension method:

These are for min and max.

```
static class Tools {
    public static int IndexOfMin<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource : IComparable<TSource> {
        int index = -1;
        int i = -1;
        TSource min = default(TSource);

        foreach (var element in source) {
            i++;

            if (index == -1 || (min != null && min.CompareTo(element) > 0)) {
                index = i;
                min = element;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    public static int IndexOfMax<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource : IComparable<TSource> {
        int index = -1;
        int i = -1;
        TSource max = default(TSource);

        foreach (var element in source) {
            i++;

            if (index == -1 || (max == null && element != null) || max.CompareTo(element) < 0) {
                index = i;
                max = element;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

Note that these methods will consider `null` to be the minimum value. The comparison with `null` is ignored for non-nullable types by the compiler.